# Using CalcHistogram on a field of study name with range value doesn't return results

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to get publication count by year from 2014-2018 for a sample topic, e.g., 'artificial intelligence'.

I worked through the example in the docs, which  generates CalcHistogram data for publications by author, and it works fine. However, when I try using a topic search I get the following error:

```
{'aborted': True,
 'expr': "And(Composite(F.FN=='artificial intelligence'),Y>2013)",
 'histograms': []}
```

The params are as follows:

```
params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
    # Request parameters
    "expr":"And(Composite(F.FN=='artificial intelligence'),Y>2013)",
    'model': 'latest',
    'attributes': 'Y,F.FN',
    'count': '5',
    'offset': '0',
})
```

Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Not sure if this helps any, but if I change the composite search to `FC.FN` instead of `F.FN` I can get results. However, something with that year is throwing it off to return zero results - `Composite(FC.FN=='artificial intelligence')`

Comment: Thanks. I just tried the query you suggested and it returns an empty dictionary. Did you actually get data? If so, weird.

Comment: I believe it was empty data :/ Sorry I couldn't help much else with it. That isn't very well documented yet, unfortunately.